# Installed MacVim, and now Eclipse is opening JSP files in it when i don't want it to

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor, macvim, eclipse-mars

I'm using this version of Eclipse

```
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
```

on Mac Sierra.  I just installed MacVim and now whenever I try and open a JSP file within Eclipse (using <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for example), the file is getting opened in MacVim instead of the Eclipse editor.  I went to

```
General -> Editors -> File Assocations
```

and added "`*.jsp`", but even after restarting Eclipse, the JSP files still open in MacVim instead of the Eclipse editor.

How can I force my `.jsp` files to open in the Eclipse editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, what you've done it's the right way.

You may have to select the right **default** to make it work:

[image: file associations]

Then you can check if the associated editors appear on file open submenu:

[image: submenu]

As you can see, *JBoss Tools JSP Editor* is highlighted to represent the default.

If these steps aren't working in your environment, there's probably a sort of *settings corruption* (experienced very often).

What you can try:

1. run *eclipse -clean -refresh*
2. create a **brand new Workspace**
3. make a new and clean eclipse installation

---

Make sure you have *Eclipse WTP* installed (or just install it):

[image]

P.S. use the update-site for your eclipse version (Mars), I'm on Neon.

Comment: There's nothing in my "ASsociated editors" window.  How do I get the JBoss JSP editor to appear there?  Is that some kind of Eclipse plugin?

Comment: *JBoss JSP Editor* is from the plugin *JBoss Tools*, but you don't have to install/use it necessarily. The **required**  plugin is *eclipse WTP*, see update